# How to add 'root' MySQL user back on MAMP?

Tags: mysql, root, mamp

On PhpMyAdmin, I removed 'root' user by mistake. I was also logged in as 'root'. How can I add the user 'root' back, on MAMP?

Answer (score 1):

When starting the MySQL daemon, you can give an `--init-file` as option, which contains SQL to be executed on startup.

Paste this SQL query into a file, e.g. `/home/me/recover-mysql-root`:

```
INSERT INTO 
    mysql.user (`Host`, `User`, `Password`, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv, File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv, Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv, Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv, Create_view_priv, Show_view_priv, Create_routine_priv, Alter_routine_priv, Create_user_priv, Event_priv, Trigger_priv, Create_tablespace_priv)
VALUES
    ('localhost', 'root', PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y');
```

Then start MySQL with this init script and it should create a new `root@localhost` account with all privileges:

```
shell> mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/recover-mysql-root &
```

For more information, consult [How to Reset the Root Password <sup>Docs</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html).